# Mockito, channel output of void function to System.out?

Tags: mockito

I have this logging class in my legacy application,
I am trying to Mock it for testing and output all messages from "WriteLog" method to System.out
This is the class

```
public abstract class LoggingServicesWorker {
   public abstract void WriteLog(ELogLevel arg0, int arg1,String arg2,String arg3);
}
```

This is what I did so far,
I am not sure how to write to System.out
Also How to tell the first argument to have any enum type (ELogLevel)?

```
LoggingServicesWorker logger = mock(LoggingServicesWorker.class);
Mockito.doNothing().when(logger).WriteLog(ELogLevel.DEBUG,anyInt(),anyString(),Mockito.eq(anyString()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Mockito#doAnswer` for executing side-effects:

```java
        doAnswer((invocation -> {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(invocation.getArguments()));
            return null;
        }))
            .when(worker)
            .WriteLog(any(ELogLevel.class), anyInt(), anyString(), anyString());
```

---

Standalone class with the default behavior for return values (and usable with Java 7):

```java
class PrintArgsToStdoutAnswer implements Answer<Object> {
    private final ReturnsEmptyValues defaultReturn = new ReturnsEmptyValues();

    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(invocation.getArguments()));
        return defaultReturn.answer(invocation);
    }
}
```

...and used in the test method:

```java
doAnswer(new PrintArgsToStdoutAnswer())...
```

Comment: In addition if you want the loglevel enum to be DEBUG,you can be more specific by using Mockito.eq static method as below

.WriteLog(eq(ELogLevel.DEBUG), anyInt(), anyString(), anyString());

Comment: Josef how will you do it in Java 7 :)  its a legacy application....

Comment: @JavaSheriff: I've addded java 7 version... I hope at least. .D